# error unbound method get() must be called with WebDriver using phantomJs

Tags: python, selenium

I followed the suggested code found on `stackoverflow`, but I'm getting an error:

```
unbound method get() must be called with WebDriver instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

my code is:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> import time
>>> from bs4 import *
>>> sns_sources = 'www.abc.com'
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS
>>> driver.get(sns_sources)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method get() must be called with WebDriver instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: You're not instantiating `PhantomJS`, so `driver` is just another name for the class `webdriver.PhantomjS`. You can't call `.get()` directly on the class without passing an instance as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the PhantomJS instance correctly

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import *
sns_sources = 'www.abc.com'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(sns_sources)
```